How should I model likes/dislikes in NoSQL?
I'm new to NoSQL and am trying to model likes and dislikes.
I've made an attempt with some messy thoughts, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
(1)
{   
    "posts": {
        "post1":{
            "id": "jmvv4e",
            "content": "Hello",
            "timestamp": 312421000,  
            "likes_number": 1,
            "likes": {
                "like1": {
                    "uid": "udfad2",
                    "timestamp": 312421241  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

(2)
{
    "posts:":{
        "post1":{
            "id": "jmvv4e",
            "content": "Hello",
            "timestamp": 312421000 
        }
    },
    "likes": {
        "likes1": {
            "post_id": "jmvv4e",
            "uid": "udfad2",
            "timestamp": 312421241  
        }
    }
}

I'm using (1) right now. Should I separate nested "likes" within "posts" as shown in example (2)?
